# suddenly error on all catch block in my android project

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-volley

I am making an app which parses jsosn using volley library. I have created seperate Parser class which contains methods to parse json. I am using that methods in my activity (JsonObjectRequest - onResponse) class to parse data. But all sudden all catch blocks giving me error like-

Required- Throwable,
Found- JsonException

my catch block

```
catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My JsonObjectRequest method

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, params,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    pDialog.hide();

                    new AGCommonMethods().AGLog(0, TAG, response.toString());
                    try {
                        AlertDialog dialog = new AGCommonMethods(mContext).showMessage("" + response.getString("message"));
                        dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                onBackPressed();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Parser Class

```
 public Object parseResponse(String response) throws JSONException {

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    try {
        if (jsonObject.has("ABC")) {
            JSONObject jsonData = jsonObject.getJSONObject("ABC");

            //Parsing Data

            return jsonObject;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you should maintain the **'Parent child'** relationship of classes.
I mean that that you can not put a Parent class above to a child class in `try-catch block.`

example :

```
catch(NullPointerException){
//Handling code of NullPointerException
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBounds){
//Handling code of ArrayIndexOutOfBounds
}
catch(Exception){
//Handeling code if all above failed to catch Exception occured
}
```

What I think you have put wrong sequence of `Exception` classes.
Try to replace the `JSONException` with `Exception` class.

Comment: No "throws "Exception" is not working. Error is same Required - Throwable.  Found- JsonException.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention that, I can build and run project without any issues. But catch blocks are marked red.